# MatConvNet: set weight for classes

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

Imagine the output of the CNN is 1x1920. The classes to be classified are `1` and `2`, with very few `2`. For example, a label for one image can be:

```
111111111111111112111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...
```

For the CNN is easy to say that the output is all `1` and fail on the `2`. So when I test the trained network the output vector 1x1920 is all `1`. So I would like to put some kind of weight to the classes so that failing on `2` has more importance. For example:

```
Weight for class 1 = 1/(2*number_of_ones);
Weight for class 2 = 1/(2*number_of_twos);
```

How can I do this?